# Git commit signing with SSH keys — stubborn error about allowedSignersFile

Tags: ssh, git

I'm trying to set up git commit signing using SSH keys (instead of PGP/GPG). It's a relatively fresh feature, added in [git 2.34](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqq8rxpgwki.fsf@gitster.g/).

I did follow all the steps (well documented in [`man git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) `gpg.ssh` section, and on blogs):

- `git config gpg.format ssh`
- `git config gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile ~/.config/git/allowed_ssh_signers`
- `git config user.signingKey ~/.ssh/git-key.ed25519`
- `git config commit.sign true`

After that, signing itself does happen — I can see the field `gpgsig -----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE-----` in `git show --pretty=raw <commit>`. But verification seems broken:

```
$ git show --show-signature HEAD
error: gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile needs to be configured and exist for ssh signature verification
commit 5957261166c2bfc8e2ef77094c74f95bcb50577b (HEAD -> main)
No signature
Author: max ulidtko <ulidtko@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 17 17:05:47 2022 +0300

    test ssh commit sign 6
$
$ git show --pretty=raw HEAD
commit 5957261166c2bfc8e2ef77094c74f95bcb50577b
tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
author max ulidtko <ulidtko@gmail.com> 1655474747 +0300
committer max ulidtko <ulidtko@gmail.com> 1655474747 +0300
gpgsig -----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE-----
 U1NIU0lHAAAAAQAAADMAAAALc3NoLWVkMjU1MTkAAAAgLzSyuIgqnSPQxnUlPhcdiKg/36
 INE7hSMLVQJLWMuo4AAAADZ2l0AAAAAAAAAAZzaGE1MTIAAABTAAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5
 AAAAQLnpQYbrfYYJe0rTIEW8hruTRmn4kcKhwhurrA9bKMnXd5b7W0wvl7auYS8LlBBXy7
 SqpIjZunnUE/EI2Q4Xiw8=
 -----END SSH SIGNATURE-----

    test ssh commit sign 6
$
$ cat $(git config gpg.ssh.allowersignersfile)
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /home/ulidtko/.config/git/allowed_ssh_signers
       │ Size: 99 B
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ ulidtko@gmail.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIC80sriIKp0j0MZ1JT4XHYioP9+iDRO4UjC1UCS1jLqO
───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$
$ git --version
git version 2.36.1
```

As shown, the file it complains about does exist, and has the expected format. (I've `cat` aliased to [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat))

What's wrong? Is this a known bug perhaps?

Comment: I cannot spot any issue with your configuration. I configured ssh sign today with a similar configuration, and it works. Is git with ssh signing working on your machine now? If there is still issues, maybe you can set up a minimal demo repo with a minimal git config files, and paste the URL, thus others can try on the demo repo.

Comment: @weakish signing works for me too; I cannot get verification to function. Just retested with git 2.37.3 — same results... "allowedSignersFile needs to be configured and exist". BTW, could SSH version be relevant? I've got `OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022`, is yours different?

Comment: I forgot to mention that verification also works. I think this may not be an issue of ssh version, my ssh version is older than yours (OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6). BTW, my git version is 2.37.0 (Apple Git-136).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, on a 3rd or 4th attempt I got this working. On 2 machines:

| OS | git --version | ssh -V |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS jammy | 2.34.1 | OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 |
| Arch Linux, last full-updated on 2022-11-21 | 2.38.1 | OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 |

Commit-graph log with `--show-signature` now looks as expected (the 2 machines sign with different keys):

[image: git log graph with signatures]

Unfortunately, I haven't realized what I've been doing wrong on the previous tries. It just works now `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

The setup isn't trivial to minimize: I use git-tracked dotfiles, submodules, and there's a good deal of symlinking stuff around involved. Anyhow, it started working somewhere near [this commit](https://github.com/ulidtko/versioned-configs/commit/071974f4f8c4ea49d117ea3feee93b8672a17717) — HTH